# Solve over Domains

Tags: equation-solving, algebra

Why do I get more real-valued solutions with Reals, than with Complexes:

```
  $Assumptions = 
 a > 0 && a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals && 
  t \[Element] Reals && t >= 0 && c1 \[Element] Reals && 
  c2 \[Element] Reals && c \[Element] Reals && B \[Element] Reals && 
  c2 > 0 && c1 < 0

Solve[Log[Abs[(B - c2)/(B - c1)]] == (a t - c) (c2 - c1), B, 
  Complexes] // Simplify

Solve[Log[Abs[(B - c2)/(B - c1)]] == (a t - c) (c2 - c1), B, 
  Reals] // Simplify
```

Comment: Since `Solve` has no `Assumptions` option, `$Assumptions` has no effect here.

Answer (score 1):

This falls under this note in the `Solve` documentation:

> Solve uses non-equivalent transformations to find solutions of transcendental equations and hence it may not find some solutions and may not establish exact conditions on the validity of the solutions found.

A simpler example would be

```
Solve[Abs[x]==2, x]
(* {{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}} *)
```

In this case, Solve does give a warning about inverse functions being used.

The general solution is in fact a circle of radius 2 centred on the origin in the complex plane. Only `Reduce` gives this.

```
Reduce[Abs[x] == 2, x]
(* -2 <= Re[x] <= 
  2 && (Im[x] == -Sqrt[4 - Re[x]^2] || Im[x] == Sqrt[4 - Re[x]^2]) *)
```

If we add a logarithm, `Solve` drops one of the solutions:

```
Solve[Log@Abs[x] == Log[2], x]
(* {{x -> 2}} *)
```

This is what you are observing.  Here `-2` is also a solution, but clearly not the only one. `2I` is also a solution.  Again, for full solution information we need `Reduce`.

The important thing to keep in mind about `Solve` is that it often uses naive transformations that are not valid in general, such as considering `Log` and `Exp` each other's inverses (while `Exp[2Pi I] == Exp[0]`, showing that this is not generally true).  This allows it to give simple solutions, and to compute them much more quickly than `Reduce` would.  We could say that `Solve` is being sloppy in a practically useful way.  The exact transformations that it is willing to make seem to depend on the domain, hence the results you see.

Because of this willingness to use non-exact transformations, the solution set from `Solve` may not be exhaustive, and if your equation contained parameters, the solutions may not be valid for all parameter values.

`Solve` has several options to control this behaviour, such as `InverseFunctions`, `MaxExtraConditions` and `VerifySolutions`.  You should look them up.

If we forbid using inverse functions, we get

```
Solve[Log@Abs[x] == Log[2], x, InverseFunctions -> False]

During evaluation of In[71]:= Solve::fulldim: The solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information.

(* {{}} *)
```

This means that there are infinitely many solutions (that circle of radius 2 in the complex plain).

If you try this option, or `MaxExtraConditions`, or `Reduce` on your equation, then Mathematica will not be able to return a solution in a reasonable amount of time. This is because there are too many parameters, and checking conditions on all of them becomes very time consuming.  However, if you restrict the domain to `Reals`, `Reduce` will be able to give a solution.